# Typescript Webpack module resolution fails only at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to migrate from grunt to Webpack on an existing Typescript project. The webpack build succeeds, even when I fail to use the correct `import` statements to import dependencies.

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "files": [
        "client/Index.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "types": []
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './client/Index.ts',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'js')
    }
}
```

`client/Index.ts`

```
//import * as $ from "jquery";
$(() => {
    $(".title").html("Jquery works");
});
```

`relevant dependencies from package.json`

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.45",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
}
...
```

Even with the import statement commented out, the webpack build completes fine-
 I guess because it's able to implicitly find the jQuery typings file. At runtime, I receive the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. This makes sense, as webpack isn't bundling `./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js`. If I uncomment the import in Index.ts, the module is bundled app runs fine. So my question is, **how do I get Webpack to fail at build time if I haven't imported a referenced module**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Typescript compiler is using its implicit type resolution by looking in node_modules, so it compiles although webpack doesn't include the actual js libraries unless you use import. This default Typescript behavior can be disabled by setting `compilerOptions.types: []`.

The posted code contains an error: `tsconfig.json` has the `"types": []` in the wrong place. The empty types array belongs in `compilerOptions.types`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": true,
        "types": []
    },
    "files": [
        "index.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

With this tsconfig, webpack fails as expected with:

`ERROR in ./client/Index.ts
(2,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.`